# Rails Address Links and Apple Maps APP

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I wrote a Rails app a while back that has a view which displays a from and to address in the view interface.  Our employees use iPads and in iOS6 used to be able to click the addresses and open them up for GPS navigation/directions.

Since iOS7 was released along with Apple Maps you can no longer click the addresses and bring up Maps for navigation.

My view code is as follows:

```
Transfer From: <%= transferred_from(call)%> <%= transferred_from_address(call) %></br>
Transfer To: <%= transferred_to(call) %> <%= transferred_to_address(call) %></br>
```

Where call is the block object being passed into a helper transferred_from/to (which lists the name of the facility as a string) and transferred_from/to_address (which displays the physical address of the locations).

Is there some sort of tag I can use to make these string objects open up in Apple Maps so I can provide some sort of mapping/GPS/NAV functionality?  Or perhaps a Rails plugin that does this?

I've dove into Rails docs and haven't seen much of anything yet, and I'm very unfamiliar with iOS development so I don't know where to start.

So to summarize, I'd simply like to have the addresses "clickable" and open Apple Maps automatically.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to pass in maps.apple.com and use a the string address as an object to query the url.

```
<%= link_to "#{transferred_from_address(call)} Click to map", "http://maps.apple.com/?q=#{transferred_from_address(call)}", :class => 'btn btn-success btn-medium' %>
```